# Google Searchbox not Validating as HTML5

Tags: javascript

I have added the Google searchbox to my HTML5 site.  When I go to the W3C validator I get an error: element gcse:search not allowed as child of element div in this context.  I was instructed by Google to put the script in a div, and cannot get the searchbox to work without it.  Can anyone help at all?  I imagine it is a problem which must arise all the time.  My code is below.  Many thanks!

```
<div id="searchbox">    
    <script>
       (function() {    
            var cx = '014531685129972083622:vk5kxnojpx0';    
            var gcse = document.createElement('script');    
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';    
            gcse.async = true;    
            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;

            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);

        })();

    </script>    
    <gcse:search> </gcse:search>    
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I imagine it is a problem which must arise all the time

Might that be the reason, perhaps, they covered this in their **official documentation** …?

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#html5:

> **HTML5-valid `div` tags**
>
> You can use HTML5-valid `div` tags as long as you observe these guidelines:
>
> - The `class` attribute must be set to `gcse-XXX`
> - Any attributes must be prefixed with `data-`.
>
> For example:
>
> `<div class="gcse-searchbox" data-resultsUrl="http://www.example.com" data-newWindow="true" data-queryParameterName="search" >`